# Can not cd to different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, windows-10

```
import os
os.system("cd /Users")
os.system("cd")
```

It does nothing except outputs:

```
C:\Users\Hudson\Documents\PyProjects
```

I have also tried:

```
import os
os.system("cd /d C:/Users")
os.system("cd")
```

But it returns the same thing.
I am using windows 10.

Comment: The Windows path separator is `\ `but not `/`! You may need to specify `\\ `in Python unless you provide a `r`aw string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.system` executes commands in a subshell, so once that subshell exits, your `cd` won't persist to your python session. I think you want `os.chdir` instead:

```py
path = 'my/path'
os.chdir(path)

os.getcwd()
/my/path
```